# Set Live Frame on Camera Capturing Image for mobile browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, webrtc, getusermedia

I have a feature of **Upload File** for uploading an **ID Card** in one of my website. When we open the website in a mobile browser we're getting option to **Take Photo/Browse Image** with the same **Upload File** button. If the user is trying to take photo and upload, then i want to restrict the user to take picture within a frame, so that user will place the id card within that frame and i can get a proper picture. Something like below(Reference from some android app)

[image]

Is this possible using html and javascript and if yes how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be done? Yes.

Lay out your web page with a `<video>` element where you want the preview to be, and with a "snap the picture" button looking the way you want it to. It's probably best to use a mobile-friendly responsive CSS framework like bootstrap to lay out the page.

Use `.getUserMedia()` with constraints that include the width and height of the image you need, and set the `<video>` element as the preview for its video stream.

When your user taps the button draw the video element into a canvas, then use [`.toBlob()` to convert the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) into an image file blob (JPEG, probably). Then post that blob to your server.

Giving every detail of the code to do this is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. But you can always ask more questions.